# TypeError: unsupported format string passed to NoneType.__format__

Tags: python, typeerror

```
first_name = input("what is your first name?")
Last_name = input("what is your last name?")

name = f'{first_name}, {Last_name}'

print("hello, {} welcome to the program!").format(name)
```

Comment: You mean `print("hello, {} welcome to the program!".format(name))`. Note what you're calling `format` on. VTC as a typo.

Answer (score 2):

`print` returns `None` - you probably meant to format a string and then pass it to `print` - in other words, your parenthesis are misplaced:

```py
print("hello, {} welcome to the program!".format(name))
```

Comment: Use `str(varname)` to convert and ensure it's a *string*.

Answer (score 0):

`format` is a method of string and you have to apply it to string. Currently, you have misplaced the `()` and it is applied on `print()` which is not correct.

You have to do this:

```py
first_name = input("what is your first name?") 
Last_name = input("what is your last name?")

name = f'{first_name}, {Last_name}'

print("hello, {} welcome to the program!".format(name))
```